# Google pagespeed insights does not recognize gzip compression

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, compression, gzip

I checked my website with [this](https://checkgzipcompression.com) and I have gzip enabled. But Pagespeed Insights says my js files are not compressed. And all those files have .js?ver=... at the end. So I guess here's the problem.
My .htaccess file looks like this and I don't have nginx in my headers, but not sure I don't have it on my server.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript 
# END WordPress
```

So how do I make compress those js files with ?ver=...?

Comment: I tried hook to remove version from files and they still not compressing, while others which had no version compressing. What the heck?

Comment: Checking in webdevtools those files they are really not compressed. So it is matter of why they were not, while other JS successfuly compressed?